# No Shopware 6 backend login possible while running ./psh.phar administration:watch

Tags: shopware, shopware6

While running `./psh.phar administration:watch` and accessing the Shopware 6 backend via `shopware.local:8080`or `192.168.33.10:8080`, I get served the develop version of Vue.js - great for, well, development.

However, trying to log in with the standard credentials fails. There is no error whatsoever in console or HTTP requests, but instead of logging in, I just get presented with the empty login form again.

It this behavior known?

Comment: Can you try clearing the browser cache and deleting the cookies?

Comment: I tried with Chrome, Safari and Edge, with vagrant on win10 and docker on MacOS. It seems that no combination works.

Answer (score 1):

Which Shopware version are you using?

There is a known problem in the 6.2.0 (RC1) and a fix which might help you: https://forum.shopware.com/discussion/comment/270549/#Comment_270549

If you're not running on v6.3 then you should consider update Shopware to the latest version.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for the link; they indeed discussed exactly my problem, but the solutions didn't work - I've tried all combinations and approaches they mentioned. An update to 6.3 is unfortunately not an option. I am running 6.2.3

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to make administration:watch work was when I switched from vagrant installation to a barebone install.
Works flawlessly now.

Comment: No luck here. Is there a way to run administration:build in dev mode? I don't care about hot reload, all I need is the Vue developer plugin for Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagyi I managed to get Vue dev tools also only working with a barebone install.